# How to read the file(.log file) in java from the specific words

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I want to read the lines from .log file after the specific word in java.

**File :**

```
Tue May 14 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Wed May 15 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Thu May 16 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Fri May 17 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sat May 18 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sun May 19 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
```

I want read the lines from *Thu May 16 08:27:25*, as a result I need the below lines :

```
Fri May 17 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sat May 18 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sun May 19 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
```

Comment: Can't you use the `grep -A 2 "Thu May 16 08:27:25" "file"` command?

Comment: Then read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java) and start writing code. But Ferrybig is fully correct: if you are just interested in fetching a line from that file; use tools like grep.

Comment: this does not really show research effort

Comment: Applications should not read application log files. They are for humans, and ultimately for judges and juries. If you need an event system, use an event system, or a database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {

        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("path\\file.txt").toPath());
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        String key = "Thu May 16 08:27:25";
        boolean start = false;
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (start) {
                result.add(line);
            }
            if (line.contains(key)) {
                start = true;
            }
        }
        for (String line : result) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //throw exception
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Fri May 17 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sat May 18 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sun May 19 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
```

The idea is :

1. Get all the lines of your files `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath());`
2. Loop throw your lines, and check if the line contain the key word `s.contains(key)` you want to check, start to fill your result List

---

For better performance and if your file contain a lot of lines, you can loop throw your file just one time, and check you can use also this solution :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("path\\file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        String lines;
        String key = "Thu May 16 08:27:25";
        boolean start = false;
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((lines = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (start) {
                result.add(lines);
            }
            if (lines.contains(key)) {
                start = true;
            }
        }
        for (String line : result) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //throw exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the hardcoded date? Making this way too complicated.

Comment: what did you mean @Qix ?

Comment: There's no need to check the date. Op didn't care about the date, and hard coding/checking a string like that is really brittle.

Comment: @Qix i think you don't understand the question the question is **I want read the lines from Thu May 16 08:27:25, as a result I need the below lines :** from focus on From so how you can understand this?

Comment: Then it should be passed in as some sort of argument. As is, this code is very fragile and reeks of code smell.

Comment: mmm, can you show us what the code should look like then @Qix instead of down-vote answer like this :)

Comment: OP should try first and ask for help if they get stuck, or maybe ask for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) when they have a working sample. :) I'm on my phone, and Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Because it promotes bad practices.

Answer (score 0):

In your you have to read the file from `Friday`, then you can simply check whether string contains friday and print all the string after that.

```
package com.stack.readfile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadLogFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader("**Path of your file**");
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String sCurrentLine;
            boolean flag=false;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(sCurrentLine.contains("Fri")){
                    flag=true;
                }
                if(flag)
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }

}
```

**Input File**

```
Tue May 14 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Wed May 15 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Thu May 16 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Fri May 17 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sat May 18 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sun May 19 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
```

**Output**

```
Fri May 17 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sat May 18 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
Sun May 19 08:27:25 EST 2013 few words
```

Hope it works for you.